# what is the compiler of c that visual studio 6 use?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-construction

what is the compiler of c that visual studio 6 use? I starting work with c and need to study more about c. In this work, we use visual c++ 6. I know have GCC, but where i can go deep about how compilation works for C language on visual c++ 6?

Comment: It uses microsofts own compiler

Comment: Like all Microsoft products, it uses their own compiler (Microsoft C++).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but i think for .cpp files they use a compiler, and for .c they use another. And every reference i found is just for C++, and no one talking about c for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the compiler of c that visual studio 6 use?

The Visual C++ IDE runs the cl.exe Microsoft compiler.

As to which standard of C compiler it is using, my guess is it's probably a C90 or C95 compiler, only because, from memory, the Visual C++ IDE dates back to the mid/late nineties. To get a more accurate date look in the About box.

But remember, like Microsoft compilers of today, Microsoft does like to create compilers that are not always fully compliant with the standard, so there may be differences.